# Regular expression works improperly

Tags: php, regex

Here iam trying to write a regular expression to validate phone no in my own sense.
Code is like as follows

```
$hai = "+458745555---55";
if (!preg_match("/^[\+]{0,1}[0-9\s(\-){0,2}]{6,15}$/", $hai)) {
    $valPhone = "Invalid phone number";
} else {
    $valPhone = "Valid phone number";
}

echo $valPhone;
```

**Rule:**

1.possible to come '+' sign in front of the string

2.only digits,-,space are possible in remaining and - should come in between 0-2

3.maximum length of string excluding '+' would be 6-15

4.We couldn't add space start and end of remaining string excluding '+' sign if it found

but the case of '-' is not working fine for me.Any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: Please show us an example of the phone number format you are looking to find

Comment: @Webeng +9578895658,+27 70 259669,+91 487-2589589,possibility of '-' sign should be a maximum of 2 and space has no any restriction..

Comment: It is not possible to use quantifiers inside a character class, so your [0-9\s(\-){0,2}] matches for any literal character inside, thus `0-9`, `\s`, `(`, `-`, `)`, `{`, `,`, `}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex does the work:

```
(?=^\+?[^+]{6,15}$)(?!(?:.*-.*){3,})^\+?\d[\d -]+\d$
```

Details:

- `(?=^\+?[^+]{6,15}$)` the whole string is 6 to 15 char long and the `+` is optional;
- `(?!(?:.*-.*){3,})` there can't be more than 2 `-`;
- `^\+?\d[\d -]+\d$` the string will contains only digit, spaces and `-`

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aO0lM0/4)

Comment: its working fine..if '+' sign is there or not minimum length of remaining string should be 6.

Comment: +5645 is valid and 5645 is invalid and and min length of digits are 6 not 5.

Comment: thanks..Thomas Ayoub..its working fine..i have one doubt..how can we restrict spaces from starting position and ending position of that remaining {6,15} string?

Comment: ya..except '+' sign i need to start it with digit and in between that space is possible..